# How can i change gridview orientation using c# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to know is there any way where I can change the `GridView` from horizontal layout to vertical layout?

Please help me out to solve this issue. Is there anyway where I can get desired output (as shown in image) through `CSS` or via `C#` code. All the data in `GridView` is dynamic. I am a fresher, please help me out.

[image]

Here is my Code:

**ASPX Code**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label
          ID="lblID"
          runat="server"
          Text='<%# 
    Eval("ID") %>'
        ></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>

      <ItemStyle />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label
          ID="lblDate_From"
          runat="server"
          Text='<%# 
       Eval("Date_From") %>'
        ></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox
          ID="txtDate_From"
          runat="server"
          Text='<%# 
      Eval("Date_From") %>'
          Width="140"
        ></asp:TextBox>
      </EditItemTemplate>
      <ItemStyle />
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label
          ID="lblEmp_Name"
          runat="server"
          Text='<%# 
      Eval("EmpName") %>'
        ></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox
          ID="txtEmpName"
          runat="server"
          Text='<%# Eval("EmpName") %>'
          Width="140"
        ></asp:TextBox>
      </EditItemTemplate>
      <ItemStyle />
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee_Designation">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label
          ID="lblEmpDesig"
          runat="server"
          Text='<%# Eval("EmpDesig") %>'
        ></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox
          ID="txtEmpDesig"
          runat="server"
          Text='<%# Eval("EmpDesig") %>'
          Width="140"
        ></asp:TextBox>
      </EditItemTemplate>
      <ItemStyle />
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code Behind C#**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        this.BindGrid();
    }
}

private void BindGrid()
{
    try
    {
        objlog.Action = "FetchEmp_Details";
        objlog.StrName = "Stored_Proc_Emp";
        dt = IncometaxDetails_Datalayer.GetData(objlog);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to transform your Data vertically and Bind it to the GridView

```
public DataSet FlipDataSet(DataSet my_DataSet)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    foreach (DataTable dt in my_DataSet.Tables)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(i));
        }
        DataRow r = null;
        for (int k = 0; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
            r = table.NewRow();
            r[0] = dt.Columns[k].ToString();
            for (int j = 1; j <= dt.Rows.Count; j++)
            r[j] = dt.Rows[j - 1][k];
            table.Rows.Add(r);
        }
        ds.Tables.Add(table);
    }

    return ds;
}
```

And where you are binding the data to GridView you have to pass a `DataSet` to the function you can perform like that:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = FlipDataSet(ds.Tables.Add(dt));
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

For more information you can check this article [Displaying vertical rows in a GridView](http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2008/04/displaying-vertical-rows-in-gridview.html)